# Run software in the cloud

Tags: windows, cloud

We often run computationally intensive software using PC's and windows based software.

Is it possible to run this software from the cloud.  I was hoping to being able to take advantage of possibly more processing power, and also access from out of the office (for example to check the progress of modelling runs).

I envision it would be similar to Google Apps, but with the flexibility to install any software I own.

For example I often run a program hydraulics program on my computer which may take say 20 minutes for a single run on my computer. During this time my computer is very unresponsive.  I often need to undertake a significant number of runs.

I would like to be able to install this program in the cloud to minimise the run time, and allow use of my desktop computer.  I may only require this additional processing power for short durations at a time (say over 2 weeks) whilst in the middle of a project sporadically throughout the year.

A candidate program may be DRAINS (www.watercom.com.au) which is typical engineering program.  Another alternative may be GIS software and data, such as QGIS.  A key challenge may be that some software has USB software locks.

Comment: What, exactly, are you asking?  Are you asking if there is currently a way to take any software you own and run it in the cloud instead of on your computer?

Comment: @boberdorf More information on what you are trying to run please.  Without this there is no way to give a good answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sure. A well-known provider in this area is Amazon Web Services, "EC2" in particular. Essentially you rent a virtual machine from them, install the OS and apps of your choice on it, etc. They have a free one-year trial for their smallest platform.

Their biggest problem is that their offerings are so diverse that it can take a while to just figure out what you want to buy from them.